# How to read the segmented data from a .dat file?

Tags: arrays, matlab, image-processing, image-segmentation

I have a .dat file created by a C++ code segment. The format of the dat file is as per these guidelines: http://users.iit.demokritos.gr/~nstam/ICDAR2013HandSegmCont/Protocol.html

This is the image file:

[image]

And here is the dat file for the above image : https://www.dropbox.com/s/q8h3psin2k67vew/color_test.dat

I can tell that the segmented words in the dat file are store in the same format as the `bwlabel` command would do.

But how do I get the data from the dat file into an array in Matlab for further processing? Suppose the first word is labeled with `1` and the second word with `2`. How do I get the `1` to a different array and the `2` to a separate array and so on. Such that I can further work on that array such as `imshow` or `im2bw` or even `regionprops`?

I tried `fopen` and `fread`. They did manage to open the file but created a single column vector having 8000+ elements.

thank you

Answer (score 1):

Best I can manage is

```
fid = fopen('color_test.dat');
im = fread(fid);
fclose(fid);

figure, imshow (reshape (im, 935, 888 ));
figure, imshow (reshape (im, 748, 1110 ));
```

Which produces these figures

[image]
[image]

But clearly something is wrong, you would have to look into the ground truth data file format.

Edit: these look far, far less painful than recaptcha.